# How to manage collision between balls in Game Maker 2 (Drag and Drop)

Tags: collision-detection, physics, game-maker

Hey there I'm using Game Maker 2 Drag and Drop for a project, I made a game like Break Out and when the ball collides with the wall it doesn't bounce, in Game Maker Studio we had *Bounce Action* but in GMS2 is deleted, can anyone help me about this issue?

[image: Collistion issue screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it'll work similair to Bounce, but it can be a workaround:

Make a wall object and place that on the edge, just outside the room, then, make a Collision Event when the ball collides with the wall object. Then inverse the movement of the ball.